# node.js axios & http , any way to bypass rate limit somehow?

Tags: node.js, http, axios, limit, rate

So I'm currently trying to access an API every second.
This works fine with 1 item but I want to be able to check a few items a second.
But there is a rate limit of like 60 requests a minute..
any way to bypass this somehow?
I'm trying not to slow it down by scaling down to less requests a minute cause of the rate limit
Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

We had a look at using `bottleneck` library for nodejs at work. its used for api rate limiting. The basic configuration allows you to set the amount of concurrent requests and how many milliseconds to wait before sending another request.

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
  maxConcurrent: 1,
  minTime: 333
});
```

I think this is good enough for you.

Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to implement it but it's now switching between them every x requests, so now it checks one item 15 times and then it checks the other item for 15 times